# arduino lowbyte and highbyte functions

Tags: arduino, byte, shift

```
int i;
float number=123.456;


void setup() 
{

  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() 
{

 byte a;

 a=lowByte(number);
```

//is this the way i extract the right most byte from a 4 bytes float? equating a byte named a with the function lowByte? Is this how i use the lowByte function? cos i couldnt compile this in my arduino IDE.

```
delay(1000);

}
```

/*
what i am trying to do is to transmit float 123.456 over zigbee. and i believe data transmission is done byte by byte. so what i am trying to do is to break this float up into 4 bytes and send them byte by byte. how i do it is i intend to use lowbyte. then i just bitshfit by 8 bits (equivalent to 1 byte) to the right. then i use lowByte again. then again bitshift by 8 and lowByte and the repeat the process until i capture all 4 bytes.

so what i want to find out is how do i break the float into 4 bytes? and store these values for them to be sent?

can it be done in a byte array?

*/

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to to the exact same thing and i found the below would work.
One approach is to use a **union** that stores the **float** value along with a unsigned char array. For example:

```
union v  {
  float         f;
  unsigned char uc[4];
};

union v val;
float f;

extern void store_byte (unsigned char v);

void test (void)  {
  val.f = 34.567;           // set floating point value
  store_byte (val.uc[0]);   // write access to the bytes of the float value
  store_byte (val.uc[1]);
  store_byte (val.uc[2]);
  store_byte (val.uc[3]);

  val.uc[0] = 0x3F;         // set float value (1.1)
  val.uc[1] = 0x8C;
  val.uc[2] = 0xCC;
  val.uc[3] = 0xCD;
  f = val.f;                // read the value as FLOAT type.
}
```